# SAS drop cloned observation

Tags: sas

I have a dataset structured with an ID and two other variables.
The id is not unique, it appears in the dataset more than 1 time (a patient could receive more than one clinical treatment).How can I drop the entire observation (the entire line) only if it is a perfect clone of a previous observation (based on the other two variable values)? I don't want to use an insanely long if statement.
Thanks.

Comment: The specific previous observation (ie if obs 9 is a duplicate of obs 8), or _any_ previous observation?

Answer (score 3):

```
proc sql;
select distinct * from olddata;
quit;
```

Sounds like an easy SQL fix. The select distinct option will remove any completely duplicate rows in a dataset if you select all columns.

Comment: If you want to create an output dataset add `create table newdata as` before the `select`.

Answer (score 0):

If you specifically want to identify if two consecutive lines are identical (but are not looking to match identical lines separated by other lines), you can use `notsorted` on a by statement and then `first` and `last` variables.

```
data want;
  set have;
  by id var1 var2 notsorted;
  if first.var2;
run;
```

That will keep the first record for any group of identical id/var1/var2, so long as they're consecutive on the dataset.  Of course if you sort the dataset `by id var1 var2` first this will always remove the duplicates, but not sorted this still works for removing consecutive pairs (or more) that are collocated.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer @JJFord's answer, but for the sake of completeness, this can also be done using the `nodupe` option in `proc sort`:

```
proc sort data=mydata nodupe;
  by id;
run;
```

What you choose as the `by` variable doesn't really matter here.  The important bit is just to specify the `nodupe` option.